# Drag PDF Page and use as image file into form

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, pdf, drag

I've got a PDF inside an HTML Object tag. I'm trying to drag a certain PDF page I'm viewing into a Div box inside a html form. I know you can drag a pdf page out of the browser and it saves as an image but I want to drag this page into a box on the html form and saves this image as data onto the database. Just not sure how I would do it in Javascript/Jquery..
[image: Drag certain PDF page into form Div]

I was thinking maybe after it's dragged into div box it saves as temporary image file in the html directory and when saving to database grabs this temp image file and then deletes it?

I tried to create an example in jsfiddle but it's disabled external pdf's... :(

Comment: I didn't know you could drag PDF pages to get images... Don't know how much this'll help, but have you tried using a HTML5/JS drag/drop uploader type of thing? https://gist.github.com/1095088 In that, you can drag an image from your desktop into the container.

Comment: It doesn't sound like what you are explaining as-is is technically possible, can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? Why is the object on the left a PDF not an image? What's the point of dragging it? Why not have a link that does that instead. So on and so forth.